# Android: Why is my if statement not executing inside the onClick method

Tags: java, android, onclick

When I print out the `user` value and the `pass` value into LogCat, the values are printed out as "A" and "a". If the `user` value is "A" and the `pass` value is "a",  I don't understand why the if statement doesn't execute. When I place the contents that are inside the if statement outside of the if statement, the `startActivity()` method operates correctly. This tells me that the if statement is the problem but I don't see how. I don't get it!

```
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            String user = username.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();

            System.out.println(user);
            System.out.println(pass);

            if (user == "A" && pass == "a")
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.android.STARTINGPOINT");
                startActivity(intent);
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `String#equals` method to compare strings instead of `==`:

```
if (user.equals("A") && pass.equals("a"))
```

Comment: I cant believe I missed that